# matplotlib imshow formatting from cursor position

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following example when I hover the cursor over the image, as well as the text I want displaying in the bottom left corner, there is also the gray scale value of the corresponding pixel. Is there a way to suppress this information (or format it)?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class test():
    def __init__(self):
        fig=plt.figure()
        ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.imshow(np.random.rand(20,20))
        def format_coord(x,y):
            return "text_string_made_from(x,y)"
        ax.format_coord=format_coord
        fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Consider to provide a screenshot of how it looks like and/or how it should look like

Answer (score 5):

One can use the `ax.format_coord` to change the `x` and `y` coordinate part of the statusbar message

[image]

by replacing the method with a custom one,

```
def format_coord(x,y):
    return "text_string_made_from({:.2f},{:.2f})".format(x,y)
ax.format_coord=format_coord
```

[image]

Unfortunately the data values in square brackets are not given by the `ax.format_coord`, but instead they are set by a `mouse_move` method of the navigation toolbar. 
What makes it worse is that the `mouse_move` is a class method which calls another method `.set_message` to actually display the message. Since the toolbar is backend dependend, we cannot simply replace it.

Instead we need to monkey patch it, such that the toolbar instance is given as first argument to the class method. This makes the solution a bit cumbersome.

In the below we have a function `mouse_move`, which sets a message to display. This is the usual `x`&`y` coordinates from the `format_coord`. It takes the instance of the toolbar as argument and would then call the toolbar's `.set_message` method. We then use another function `mouse_move_patch`, which calls the `mouse_move` function with the toolbar instance as argument. The `mouse_move_patch` function is connected to the 'motion_notify_event'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mouse_move(self,event):
    if event.inaxes and event.inaxes.get_navigate():
        s = event.inaxes.format_coord(event.xdata, event.ydata)
        self.set_message(s)

class test():
    def __init__(self):
        fig=plt.figure()
        ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.imshow(np.random.rand(20,20))
        def format_coord(x,y):
            return "text_string_made_from({:.2f},{:.2f})".format(x,y)
        ax.format_coord=format_coord

        mouse_move_patch = lambda arg: mouse_move(fig.canvas.toolbar, arg)
        fig.canvas.toolbar._idDrag = fig.canvas.mpl_connect(
                        'motion_notify_event', mouse_move_patch)

t = test()
plt.show()
```

This will result in the desired ommitance of the data values in the status bar message

[image]

Comment: I left out the part about *"(or format it)"*  from the question. Are you interested in getting a solution to this as well? If so, please tell me, but I did not want to make it more complicated as it needs to be for the moment.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.